# How to pass two parameters to a thymeleaf template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf

i have a Thymeleaf template for email, and I am trying to pass two parameters to create an URL.

The part I am talking about looks like this:

```
<p><span>To accept the protocol click <a th:href="@{http://localhost:8080/accept/(invoiceId=${invoiceId}),(contractorEmail=${email})">HERE</a></span></p>
```

When I run the function that should create and send an email, I get:

```
Could not parse as expression: "@{http://localhost:8080/accept/(invoiceId=${invoiceId}),(contractorEmail=${email})" (template: "mailTemplate" - line 7, col 47)
```

How can I pass both parameters to the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all documented in Thymeleaf's [Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html).

```
@{http://localhost:8080/accept/(invoiceId=${invoiceId},contractorEmail=${email})}
```